# For loop inside for loop for generating strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have the following code generating an image url based on an array of objects and their properties:

```
for (let s = 0; s < amount; s++) {
   console.log(projects[s].imagelocation + projects[s].images[0]); 
}
```

As an example this gives me the following output:

```
img/EnergyGoStix-assets/GoStix1.jpg
img/Premier-assets/PremierStudios1.jpg
img/Quickstix-assets/QuickStix1.jpg
img/MotherMonster-assets/MotherMonster1.jpg
img/Stepping-assets/SteppingBooklet1.jpg
```

However, the `images` property is actually an array. This array contains multiple image sources such as `GoStix1.jpg`, `GoStix2.jpg`, etc. This number of image sources varies between the projects.

How do I create a loop within a loop that would incorporate `images.length` where it will first go through each project and generate all image sources, prior to moving onto the next one?

P.S - Sorry for the terrible post title, had no idea what to call this. If anyone can come up with a better one to help be more precise, please let me know so I can update it.

Comment: `for (let i = 0; i < projects[s].images; i++)` ?

Comment: Nested loops - search for it

Comment: `for (let s = 0; s < amount; s++) {
   console.log(projects[s].imagelocation + 
   for (let i = 0; i < projects[s].images; i++) {
         projects[s].images[i])
   }; 
}`

Comment: @VLAZ I understand the suggestion that you propose but I am not sure where to put it.

Comment: "*How do I create a loop within a loop*" - seems like you already know everything you need. Can you show us your attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just nest the loops, and be careful to use different variable names in the initialization of each.

```
for (let s = 0; s < amount; s++) {
  for (let i = 0; i < projects[s].images.length; i++) {
    console.log(projects[s].imagelocation + projects[s].images[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Better than another for loop would be to use an Array iteration method:

```
for (let s = 0; s < amount; s++) {
  projects[s].images.forEach(image => {
      console.log(projects[s].imagelocation + image);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
for (let s = 0; s < amount; s++) {
for (let y in  projects[s].images){
   console.log(projects[s].imagelocation + projects[s].images[y]); 
}
}
```

If you want to display images array only in one console, use:

```
for (let s = 0; s < amount; s++) {
   console.log(projects[s].imagelocation + [...projects[s].images]); 
}
```

Comment: @Sean, thanks for pointing that out. I make an error, has updated it